# Multiple Cases in Switch with Overlaping operations

Tags: c, switch-statement

Is there any way in C to go through different case labels that each label does a specific operation and some in common operations without rewriting the common operation?
I mean instead of this:

```
switch(input)
{
case A:
//do nothing
break;
case B:
data = 0x02;
output = data;
break;
case C:
data = 0x04;
output = data;
break;
case D:
data = 0x08;
output = data;
break;
default:
//do nothing
break;
}
```

Use something like below but output doesn't stuck at 0x08 for B,C and D inputs:

```
switch(input)
{
case A:
//do nothing
break;
case B:
data = 0x02; //specific operation for B
case C:
data = 0x04; //specific operation for C
case D:
data = 0x08; //specific operation for D
output = data; //common operation for all B,C,D labels
default:
//do nothing
break;
}
```

I need if input is B,C or D the output subsequently assigned to 0x02, 0x04 or 0x08. Is it possbile? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible - use a `goto`.  Whether or not it is advisable may be another matter...

Comment: Your first version is readable and understandable, there is nothing wrong with it. Trying to do clever tricks with a `switch` statement is bug-prone and not worth saving a couple of lines of code.

Comment: @BJMyers I prefer not to use goto but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no obvious need to re-arrange the original code, but it is certainly possible:

```
bool write_output = true;

switch(input)
{
  case B: data = 0x02; break;
  case C: data = 0x04; break;
  case D: data = 0x08; break;

  case A:
  default: 
    write_output = false; 
    break;
}

if(write_output)
{
  output = data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way, which shows more clearly that some cases behave differently than others:

```
switch(input) {
  case A:
    //do nothing
    break;

  default:
    switch (input) {
      case B:    data = 0x02;  break;
      case C:    data = 0x04;  break;
      case D:    data = 0x08;  break;
    }
    output = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

switch-case acts like a fall through. After the first `case` match, all the subsequest `case` statements will be executed until a `break` statement is encountered.

Suppose `input == 'C'`, in such a case first `data` will be set to `0x04` and then in the absence of break statement, data will be reassigned to `0x08` for `D` ( fall through all the case statements).

Basically, for inputs `B`, `C` and `D` data will be set to `0x08`. This will not be correct for `B` and `C` cases where you want a different value for `data`

I hope this is not what you want as per your original cases.

Comment: Yes I don't want to do that. I tried to write a code that works like original one but without rewriting the common operation more than once

Comment: Exactly. I hope you now understand how `switch-case` works. The second code re-arrangement will not work for you.